# TWebRequest.PathInfo returned isn't correct and doesn't match API reference

Tags: delphi, iis, isapi

I have a legacy ISAPI webapp using TWebModule in Delphi 7.  :o  When running on older IIS it works fine, when running on newer IIS I am having a problem with PathInfo not following the API specs.  I don't know at which point IIS has stopped working, but IIS 6.0 works and IIS 10.0 doesn't.  Right now I'm just trying to get this legacy program working again on newer IIS.

I have attached a BeforeDispatch event to TWebModule, and I have a debug message being logged to a log file:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  DebugU.Write_DB_MSG(
      'Before dispatch: ' + request.ContentFields.text + 'URL  ' + 
      request.URL + ' Query ' + request.QueryFields.Text + '  Host ' + 
      request.Host + ' PATH ' + request.PathInfo);

  {rest of my code here}
end;
```

On older IIS, what's displayed for request.PathInfo follows what the API describes:

[PathInfo API reference](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/HTTPApp_TWebRequest_PathInfo.html)

However on newer IIS the PathInfo being returned, if using the example provided in the API reference above, is "/art/gallery.cgi/mammals" instead of the expected "/mammals"

Is this a problem that would be resolved with newer Delphi or TWebModule?  Is there a setting in IIS that is wrong?

I normally probably would have just worked around this quirk in the software, but since the PathInfo is being calculated incorrectly they don't match with the PathInfo for the Actions and thus none of the mapped Actions are being called and instead just falls back to the defaultaction.

Comment: Hi @da66en, did you find out the solution for this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why your path info is changed, but you have a fairly simple work-around to get it working, until you figure out the core problem:

In the BeforeDispatch event or the default action handler, depending on what else you're doing there, just examine the last component of the path, and based on that, pass everything on to the proper handler.

You can do it with `extractfileName` - it will return the last part of `PathInfo` in your case - whatever is after the final slash:

```
if extractfileName(PathInfo) = 'mammals' then
MammalHandler(Sender,Request, Response,Handled);
```

---

If you have a lot of different requests to handle, set up a mapping dictionary - something like this:

```
type

THandlerDictionary=TDictionary<string, TWebActionItem>;

...

fHandlerDictionary:=THandlerDictionary.create;
fHandlerDictionary.add('mammals', MammalsHandler);

...
```

Then you can write something like this:

```
WebModule.DefaultHandler(Sender: TObject;  Request: TWebRequest;
Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);

var handlerPath:string;

begin 

...

handlerPath:=extractfileName(Request.PathInfo) ;
fHandlerDictionary[handlerPath](Sender,Request, Response,Handled); 

...

end;
```